# Angular SSR - remove state script tag

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular-ssr

Here I'm using Angular Universal SSR for SEO Friendly sites. but in view source, I'm getting a script tag generated automatically at the end of the body tag with id {{project-name}}-state. How to escape this? example screenshot

[image: 1]

I tried removed that script tag from server.ts, after removing few contents which was dynamically generated are missing on the view source

Comment: Why does it bother you?

Comment: @Pieterjan I tried this for keyword stuffing for SEO purposes

Comment: It does not matter for SEO purposes, it's just used by angular universal to transfer the state from server side to client side